# Any automation tool to diff web pages showed in Browser

Tags: javascript, rest, web, automated-tests, diff

I’ve written a RestAPI which can transform html content without affecting web page rendering in Browser, next I'd like to test it by comparing transformed html with original html, the test gets successful result only if what they display in Browser are coincident. Can any one recommend any tool to automate the test?

Thanks